# Reverse polarity protection using back to back NMOS

Tags: protection, nmos, polarity, reverse-polarity

Designing a circuit to measure short circuit current of a power supply every second. Measurement will be on for about 50ms every second. Heat design has been made for this about of time not constant current flow. Current can be up to 15A and the voltage up to 60V when in voltage source.

Want to provide reverse current protection in case the user connects polarity wrong so the components don't overheat. If this occurs I have tested the board and it goes over 180º. In normal mode no component goes over 45º.

Have designed following circuit but it does not work. Works fine in forward mode. In reverse polarity mode once I switch ON both MOSFETs and its fine but I cannot switch them back off even if the gate is set to GND and heat rises drastically.

[image]

Any thoughts what could be wrong?

---

Built new circuit but it's failing when V1 is higher than 50V.

[image]

Comment: Well, if your voltage source is reversed, then (+) is at the bottom, and the gate is not set to GND, it's set to (+), so your bottom NMOS is switched on and the top NMOS is conducting through the body diode.

Comment: Why not just use a [single PMOS for reverse polarity protection](https://www.google.com/search?q=pmos+reverse+pololarity+protection&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS906US906&oq=pmos+reverse+pololarity+protection&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l6.6105j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)?

Comment: I dont think the single PMOS will work in my application as once the PMOS goes ON voltage drops to almost 0 at the source of the PMOS, so I would not be able to switch it back OFF. I haven't tried it but that's my thought

Comment: It would be less ambiguous to discuss your schematic if you could use reference designators. Particularly since you are discussing reverse polarity power application so even if I say "upper NMOS"  it may be ambiguous if I mean upper in forward polarity or upper in reverse polarity.

Comment: I haven't thought this through all the way but usually when I use back-to-back mosfets I connect the sources together instead of the drains, and put a resistor from source to gate. This way I can be sure that both mosfets see the same control voltage and are always in the same state. In your case, the source of the upper transistor is connected to V+ and the gate is pulled to V- with a resistor. I would think that reverse polarity in that case might destroy some stuff.

Comment: Also, under reverse polarity at 60V, whatever is connected to G will be destroyed and will also probably cause the lower mosfet to turn on.

Comment: Those are the sources connected together. You are however right about the resistor. Let me test that

Comment: Oh, I was confused. But the pulldown is to the drain of the lower fet. If the pulldown is to the mutual source, then that will guarantee that Vgs is zero unless you drive it some other way. Under reverse polarity, the drain of the lower fet is a pullup not a pulldown.

Comment: Then you just put a diode in series with G such that G can be driven high under normal operation but under reverse polarity it will be reverse biased.

Comment: 15 Amps through 20 mOhms is 4.5 Watts. Can your CS resistor handle 4.5 Watts for 50 ms over and over again?

Comment: No problem with the resitor. It is actually 16mOhm. Three 50mOhm in parallel. 1W each. About 10º temperature rise

Comment: Changing the resitor from gate to the common source did the job, my mistake on the schematic thinking of a one single mosfet circuit. Now the problem is that, as you said, for high voltage switching the top NMOS is failing. Should I add a zener diode between gate and source to prevent this?

Comment: See my answer. If you have more questions, ask them under my answer and I will know they are fresh questions.

Comment: _"Built new circuit but its failing when V1 is higher than 50V" - which MOSFETs are you using?

Comment: IRFB4510. Sorry I posted that below on a comment.

Answer (score 1):

This is more or less what I have in mind. When I use back-to-back FET's I almost always start by pulling the gates to the sources with a resistor. This is a foolproof way to make sure they will be off in normal operation. Then I go from there.

In this case, D1 is needed to make sure that during reverse polarity connection no current flows through the body diode of M2 into the control circuitry I assume is connected to G. If that were to happen, the MOSFET's could be damaged as well as anything connected to G.

In addition to what I have shown, you may want Zener protection in parallel with R1 to make sure Vgs never gets high enough to damage M1 and M2.

Note that if and when M1 and M2 fail, you will have a short circuit across the power rail. So you should give some thought to the consequences of that to make sure they are acceptable. It is a foreseeable failure, not a one in a million freak occurrence. So the consequences need to be acceptable, or if not, you may need to add a fuse or some form of detection, etc.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCbXZv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Circuit is correct and working. It is however failing at switching voltages over 50V. I am going to add a zener diode and test it and will post back.

Comment: 0


So I added two zener diodes bak to back parallel to R1 but circuit is failing when V1 is higher than 50V, even when polarity is OK. Diode from M1 is going to short-circuit. I am using IRFB4510 NMOS specified at 100V. Following circuit is what I built. Any ideas why M1 is failing?

Comment: I can see your deleted post. Not really sure why its failing. What EXACTLY are the steps to make it fail? Does it fail when you turn on the FET, or when you turn it off, or the moment you connect the power supply? Sometimes depending on what is going on with wires or inductive loads, etc, there can be large voltage transients when you switch a FET. Even 2x over-voltage is possible for example if you try to turn off an inductive load.

Comment: Another possibility is that the FET is turning on too slowly. During the slow turn-on time it may be dissipating a lot of power. Especially if there is capacitance on the 50V rail.

Comment: Its failing when I turn the FET ON. Inmediately when it goes on. I though about it turning on slowly and the power thing so I turn the current of the power source to only 400mA to avoid that and it's still failing so it must be a voltage thing

Comment: Now that the circuit works I don't really see the point in D1 as the current going into the gate is limited by R1. Even if current runs through the diode of M2 at 60V this will only be 0.6mA at most if R1 is 100K. Also don't see the point in the zener diodes if I can guarantee the voltage at the gate to be below 10V. Unless of course you could have 60V at the source at some point which I guess could occur if I don't have D1. In any case either D1 or the zener diodes should be enough, but not both

Comment: D1 is there to protect the gates during reverse polarity connection. The problem is that I don't know exactly what you are using to drive the gates and whether there is a separate power supply, etc. A lot of unknown details. So I put D1 in there to cover scenarios which may or may not be applicable. It is definitely not needed in forward mode, though. Only for reverse polarity. If you are passing your reverse polarity test without it you can omit it. The Zeners may not be needed. They should only be needed for transient type events.

Comment: I'm driving the gate with an optocoupler and are passing the reverse polarity tests. Will do some more testing on the board and print a final schematic. Thank you for your help

Comment: You are welcome! After you post your final schematic as an answer to your own question, you can accept that answer (I think the system may make you wait before you can accept it). It is OK to accept your own answer on questions. From a bookkeeping perspective it is desirable to eventually have questions get accepted answers.

Answer (score 1):

> Built new circuit but its failing when V1 is higher than 50V

It should be be failing well below 50 V. Your circuit does *not* provide reverse polarity protection.

Ground should be applied to the MOSFET Source terminals, so that V2 is directly connected between the Gate and Source of each FET. The circuit looks like this:-

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5bA5b.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

(R1 is provided to ensure that the FETs stay turned off if V2 is disconnected)

The FETs should be rated for at least the maximum expected voltage (including spikes caused by wiring inductance etc.) preferably 20% higher to give a safety margin. Most FETs rated higher than 60 V are 'standard' Gate drive, which requires 10 V to turn on fully.

Comment: Are you commenting on the 2nd circuit (which I suggested to the OP) or the original circuit the OP drew on paper? I think the 2nd circuit does in fact provide reverse polarity protection. It is actually not all that different from yours. It SOUNDS like the OP is having a problem when switching with 50V or above. But I am not 100% sure.

Comment: @mkeith I simulated his new circuit in LTspice and it did not work properly with polarity reversed (drew high current continuously, not controlled by V2). The problem above 50V may be due to Drain-Source breakdown (few FETs that turn on fully with 5V can withstand >50V).

Comment: The new circuit I built and suggested by mkeith is failing in normal polarity, not in reverse. The FET I'm using is IRFB4510 and has a max gate threshold voltage of 4V. In reverse polarity below 50V it works fine.

Comment: Did some more testing and found the problem to be the G-S voltage. With voltages above 6V I have tested the input at 63V and 5A for over 50 switches and works fine. When I bring G-S voltage down to 5V it fails inmediately. According to the datasheet it seems like it should work at 5V but I guess its not all true

Comment: With respect to whether the ground is at the sources or at the Drain of M2 I guess being at the sources is better but it complicates my circuit as I have ADC for measuring voltage at the source and the shunt resistor and are referenced to the drain of M2

Comment: Put the current shunt between M1 Source and ground. Use a differential amplifier to measure PSU voltage (and shunt voltage too if you want high accuracy). You could control M2 separately so that it is permanently turned on when correct PSU polarity is detected (I didn't put these changes in my circuit because I just wanted to show the minimum alterations needed for correct operation). If the PSU _must_ be connected directly to ground then you will have to use a level shifter or galvanically isolated Gate drive, or a high-side switch - all of which are more complicated than a differential amp.

Comment: The IRFB4510 is designed for 10V Gate drive. 5V is marginal (remember that the graphs in the datasheet are for a _typical_ unit, not one with max threshold voltage).